# Calculate Pagerank of three nodes

Tags: information-retrieval

Soon I will have an exam where I will be asked to calculate pagerank. So far, I have been thought to use power iteration. However, this can be a very expensive operation to do during an exam, especially when most of the times, the number of nodes is just 3.

Is there any better algorithm to calculate the pagerank of only 3 websites involved?

Answer (score 5):

There is a formula for the PageRank which involves inverting an $n\times n$ matrix. When $n = 3$ this is not too hard. For inverting the matrix, use the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_3.C3.973_matrices) given on Wikipedia, which is just a special case of the general formula involving the [adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix).

That said, I see absolutely no reason why you would ever have to calculate PageRank by hand. That's what we have computers for. If you are given such an exercise in an exam, the matrix will probably have some very simple structure which will make it easier to handle by hand.

Comment: sorry Yuval, I have gone through it again. I think inverting the matrix will lead to yet another linear system to solve. Isn't there any 3x3 property that I am not seeing?

Comment: Use the formula here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank#Algebraic. When you're inverting a matrix, you're solving a linear system.

Comment: Can you give some other hint on that, I am confused how I construct the stochaistic matrix

Comment: No, now it's time for you to revise the material on your own. Good luck!

Comment: I don't think there is a need for finding the inverse, if I can just use the transpose and solve the linear system. My aim is to avoid that

Comment: You can solve linear equations instead of inverting. In Wikipedia you can find the linear system you need to solve.

Comment: One very last question, can I choose any d from 0<d<1 or do I need to find the right value for d?

Comment: There is no "right value for $d$", since $d$ is a parameter. According to Wikipedia, a common choice for $d$ is 0.85. The right value of $d$ for you depends on your application. If your application is solving an exam, then $d$ has to be specified by the examiner. In real life, probably some experimentation reveals a good value of $d$.

Comment: since d is scalar, solving that equation would then result to a matrix, not to a vector, correct? how do I get the page rank from that? I now understood what d represents (transport probability), thanks

Comment: I suggest you set aside a few hours and try to understand PageRank back from first principles. Only if you still haven't got things worked out, come back here. Stackexchange is not a tutoring site.

Comment: I absolutely know that. I am really new to this field, so most of the things you mentioned are totally new to me :( I think this is the answer that reflects my level and keeps its simplicity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ly5zHY7DI70

Answer (score 1):

A less formal answer, but nice step by step strategy is described in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ly5zHY7DI70)

Comment: After a bit more learning. this is equivalent to solving a linear system